# How to include ID Query Parameter of URL in a Fetch call in JavaScript?

Tags: azure-functions-core-tools

I have a web page that contains the videoID in the url link(?id=videoID). An example of my web page:

I want to include the same videoID as a query parameter in it's request to my Azure Logic app. I am not too sure, how to include this in the present Fetch call(in my code below) that I am making in my web page(similar to the "languages"). Basically, on a Form Submit, how do we include videoID query parameter in the URL for the fetch call?

*What I tried to do was:*

Answer (score 0):

Updated `handleSubmit()` to retrieve the `videoId` and pass it to `fetchForLanguage()`:

```
function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const data = new FormData(event.currentTarget)
  const languages = data.getAll('language')
  console.info('languages selected:', languages)

  let params = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search.substring(1));
  let videoId = params.get("id"); // Video ID

  fetchForLanguages(languages, videoId)
    .then((result) => console.log('got result:', result))
}
```

Updated `fetchForLanguage()` to include `videoId` in POSTed data:

```
function fetchForLanguages(languages, videoId) {
  console.info('starting fetch for', languages)
  return fetch("https://prod-00.westus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/366b73ac2f354e2799b87db3c0241adc/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=FdEthGEqPF7UUYf4pB69Q--ZxnZRKngXhFZnVjPxyc4", { // this is my azure  provided endpoint instead
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      languages: languages,
      videoID: videoId
    })
  }).then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
    }
    return response.json()
  })
}
```

Note that `videoID` (uppercase "ID") is the key I assume you want to send to Azure, based on your original request, not to be confused with `videoId`, which is the name of the Javascript variable I'm storing it in. I'm also assuming the original incoming parameter is named `id` but you can change that in `handleSubmit()`.

Comment: Hi Kmoser, thanks for your help on this. I ran the JavaScript with your changes, and I am still getting failure when running it on Azure. Here is the error I see:Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Get_Video_Captions' inputs at line '1' and column '1950': 'The template language expression 'encodeURIComponent(triggerOutputs()['queries']['id'])' cannot be evaluated because property 'queries' doesn't exist, available properties are 'headers, body'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions for usage details.' Perhaps it isn't able to recognize ID query parameter?

Comment: I also posted a  snapshot of the error above in my question.

Comment: I am wondering maybe I should use  should include `triggerOutputs()['queries']['id']),` in the javascript (in the body rather than in the query, and use this body variable instead of triggerOutputs()['queries']['id'])? Is it possible?

Comment: Another reason why this code might not be working is because the key is "videoId: According to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/videoindexer-v2/#get-video-captions

Comment: @Peter If the only available properties are `headers` and `body`, perhaps the video ID is embedded within the `headers` property? Just a guess, but maybe something like `triggerOutputs()['headers']['id'])`? Note that `id` might have to change to `videoId`.

Comment: I tried both` header` and `body`, but they both are failing. When I tried `body` like this: triggerOutputs()['body'][videoID']). It gave a 404 status code. I posted the snapshot in my question above. For some reason it is not recognizing the videoID, is it something with the code?

Comment: Is there a way with Azure to display the return value of `triggerOutputs()`? That would tell you definitively what to do.

Comment: How do we include `triggerOutputs()['body'][videoID'] ` in javascript (in the body rather than in the query, and use this body variable instead of triggerOutputs()['body']['id'])? Is there way to make this change in your updated code?

Comment: by the way let videoId = params.get("id"); // Video ID <<< here, your params.get("id") is null in jsfiddle.  I am wondering how to put the value in the code instead of trying to get it from params? Could you please demo that?

Comment: how can we  put the value in the code instead of trying to get it from params? Because when I will use the page, calling it with the id in the query, yes, the value will be there. But as is, in the jsfiddle, as you are not passing it when querying, so it's not having the value

Comment: It's not clear where you want to get the video ID from. In your post you said you want to get it from a form submission. In your latest comment it sounds like you want to hard-code it. Which is it?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, my initial thought ir was to get it from Form submission. But after seeing  that  `let videoId = params.get("id"); // Video ID <<< here, your params.get("id")` is null in jsfiddle. Is it possible to change the code to just hard-code it? I think hard-code it might be best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212434/discussion-between-kmoser-and-peter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) and [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) classes to manipulate the parameters.

```
videoId = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get('id')

azure = new URL("https://prod-00.westus2.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/366b73ac2f354e2799b87db3c0241adc/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=FdEthGEqPF7UUYf4pB69Q--ZxnZRKngXhFZnVjPxyc4")

params = azure.searchParams
params.append('videoId', videoId)

azure.searchParams = params
fetch(azure.toString(),
   // Other parameters
)
```